# Writing into file with cpp WxWidgets

Tags: c++, file, wxwidgets

I have this code:

```
wxFile download_xml; //declaration of file
download_xml.Open(wxT("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\opti-med_kamsoft_osoz\\dist\\Debug\\MinGW-Windows\\pobrane_badania\\pobrane_badania.xml")); //directory (file is there - I checked)

char buffor[20000];

//Here I download content for the file
bool is_download = LIBRARY.GetDispositionOrder(buffor);

if(is_download)
{

    tex_box->AppendText(wxT("OSOZ_GetDispositionMedicalOrder True\n"));

    //trying to save results
    bool is_write_ok = download_xml.Write(buffor,20000);

    if (is_write_ok){tex_box->AppendText(wxT("ok\n"));}
    else {tex_box->AppendText(wxT("fail\n"));}
}
```

The problem is that I get permissions error like this:

[image]

I don't understand why? I dont have this file open in any editor/file commander. File is not set for read only, and I gave all permissions to widows users.

Why can this happen?

Comment: in newer windows versions you often need administrative privileges to write outside of your home directory, did you check the privileges, or only the read-only flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default file permission for `wxFile::Open` is `wxFile::read` ([documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxfile.html#wxfileopen)).

Try to pass `wxFile::write` (alternatively: `wxFile::read_write`) as the second argument to your `Open` function. This will enable your file to be **written**, not just **read**.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Big Thx.